# Sobolev spaces for vector-valued functions

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $ \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be open. How is defined the space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for vector valued functions $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^3 $? What is the norm in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Something like the sum of the $W^{1,p}$ norms of the individual vector components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Sobolev $p$-norm for scalar-valued functions is
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}^p=\int_\Omega |f|^p +|\nabla f |^p dm.
\end{align*}
Here, you should not hesitate to think of $|\cdot|$ as the underlying Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}$ measuring the size of the output of the function and its gradient. Replacing this with any norm $\|\cdot\|_E$ (recall they are all equivalent) on $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives you the Sobolev norm on vector valued functions as
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}^p=\int_\Omega \|f\|_E^p +\|\nabla f \|_E^p dm.
\end{align*}
In particular, I guess the standard choice would be to to choose either
\begin{align*}
\|x\|_E =\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2},
\end{align*}
which is MaoWao's suggestion, or
\begin{align*}
\|x\|_E =\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|,
\end{align*}
which gives the Sobolev norm mentioned in the comment by daw.

Comment: You may want $W^{1,2}$ to be a Hilbert space, so the $\ell^1$-norm might not be the best choice. But of course it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: I agree, but for general $p$-norms it is often convenient to use $l^1$ so the sum "splits" (if for no other reason then aestethics..). For $p=2$, the Euclidean $l^2$ norm is probably advised.

Comment: Thank you. How can I define the norm $\| \nabla f\|^p_{E}$ for the matrix $\nabla f$?

Comment: You can sum over just the diagonal elements and proceed in analogy to $\|f\|_E^p$. This works since the (matrix) trace bounds the eigenvalues and thus it suffices to bound the spectral behavior of the matrix $\nabla f$. Again though, any norm will do (and is equivalent to any other): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm